# Getting Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.) error from django in C#

Tags: c#, django, django-csrf, csrf-token

I'm sending data to a django application using C# code:

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    NameValueCollection postData = new NameValueCollection()
           {
              { "user_id", "12345" }
           };
    string pagesource = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(client.UploadValues(url_ad, postData));
}
```

But I'm getting this error:

> Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.)

Code to get data in django `views.py`:

```
def get_user_id(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_id = request.POST.get('user_id')
        record = User.objects.filter(user=user_id)
        if not record:
            new_user = User(user = user_id)
            new_user.save()
        return HttpResponse(
            json.dumps(response_data),
            content_type="application/json"
        )
    else:
        return HttpResponse(
            json.dumps({"nothing to see": "this isn't happening"}),
            content_type="application/json"
        )
```

I know what the error is and how to fix it in web applications, But I don't know how to solve it when sending data using C#.

Also since I'm not using .NET framework 4.5+ I can't use `HttpContent` which I heard is able to somehow fix this.

So how can I fix it with `WebClient` or any other available solutions for .NET framework 4?

Answer (score 1):

You can exempt the csrf check by putting the following decorator in your function:

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt
def get_user_id(request):
   ...
```

Comment: Although its not a great idea to disable this protection, I tried it but it just did shutdown the error but the code stopped working for some reason

Comment: Probably because response_data is not defined.

Comment: Yeah I guess that was the problem. But still I think its not the right solution